# Django Google App Engine, how to serve static files using Google Cloud Storage

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a Django app running on Google App Engine.

I want that all the requests for static content will be served not by the Django app but a Google Cloud Storage bucket on which I've already uploaded all the content that the app needs.

The storage bucket has public access and I can see the static content with the browser with urls like this:

https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/static/image.jpg

Basically what I need to know is how to configure the app.yaml file so that requests like these:

https://www.mydjangoapp.com/static/image.jpg

will be served by the storage:
https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/static/image.jpg

With Ngix/Apache this is a standard thing, but how can I achieve this on GCP? I did not find a working solution on the documentation. Thanks

Comment: you can write a webapp handler, which get data from gcs and then serve it

Comment: Thanks but this is a thing I want to avoid, the app itself must not spend computing resources in serving static content, it's a best practice

Comment: yaa, but as per my understanding without it, you can't reroute, even with dispatch.yaml

Comment: In this case Google App Engine would have severe limitations serving static content separately is a standard feature, I can not believe GAE lacks of this

Answer (score 2):

You can set this up directly in your `settings.py` configuration file by making your STATIC_URL point to your Google Cloud Storage bucket, like so:

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/static/'
```

Your static files urls will then be constructed from this base path and served directly from Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Already tried this solution but it does not work, error 404 for any static file. Do I need to make any change in the app.yaml maybe?

Comment: @johncarlof - Use the web browser debugger (press F12) and verify the path that your web server has generated to Cloud Storage.

Comment: By the way, I'm using Google App Engine Standard. Should I switch to Google App Engine Flexible to get access to Cloud Storage from the app?

Comment: Did you do [this configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/serving-static-files#serving_files_from) before on your bucket?